# undefined local variable or method `main_app' on helper test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rails-engines

I got error on RSpec running my helper test on Rails Main Application (with further plugins)

```
 1) MenuHelper maintence menu 
   Failure/Error: before { menu = build_menu_maintence() }
 NameError:
   undefined local variable or method `main_app' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_3::Nested_1:0x007f92f561f280>
 # ./app/helpers/menu_helper.rb:37:in `eval'
 # (eval):1:in `block in build_menu_items'
 # ./app/helpers/menu_helper.rb:37:in `eval'
 # ./app/helpers/menu_helper.rb:37:in `block in build_menu_items'
 # ./app/helpers/menu_helper.rb:23:in `each'
 # ./app/helpers/menu_helper.rb:23:in `build_menu_items'
 # ./app/helpers/menu_helper.rb:15:in `build_menu'
 # ./app/helpers/menu_helper.rb:48:in `build_menu_maintence'
 # ./spec/helpers/menu_helper_spec.rb:11:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Comment: what type of engine is it? full, mountable?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I had success with the following in a mountable Engine:

```
def main_app
  Rails.application.class.routes.url_helpers
end

main_app.root_path
```

Comment: where do you put this yo? in a rails_helper?

Comment: I would also like to know where to put this.

Comment: Think this goes in `rails_helper.rb` or `spec_helper`. I guess I lost the code where I used it. You can put it anyhwere, engines will try to call it like so http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Engine.html#class-Rails::Engine-label-Using+Engine-27s+routes+outside+Engine