# main_app Namespace unknown in Rspec, only in unit suite tests (batch)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I have a helper class, ApplicationHelper, that has a method, build_links(). I have another class, AppleClass, that refers to that method.

```
AppleClass 
  def foo
    ....
    build_links
  end
end

ApplicationHelperClass
   def build_links
     main_app.blah_path(1)
   end
end
```

The complication here is that there's an Engine, so I usually explicitly reference "main_app.blah_path" not just "blah_path".

The test against foo  passes by itself, in its file, and when I run all helpers. It fails, though, when I include it in all the unit tests - "rake spec:suite:unit", and with our entire suite. All Apple tests pass, all ApplicationHelper tests pass. The only failing ones are when one method is referring to the other method, in routes, outside of the engine, in the full suite.

```
`undefined local variable or method `main_app' for #  
<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_45::Nested_1:0x007fc134b30130>`
```

My suspicion is that the test helper, or some config, is not loading the engine's routes early enough, and thus links to "main_app" don't make sense. If I remove main_app, the test fails until it's run in the main suite.

Does anyone have tips on troubleshooting what's really going on? Also, could I kickstart the routing somehow in test_helper?

ruby-1.9.3-p385, rails 3.2.13, rspec 2.13.0

Comment: Note: the AppleClass is a mailer

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and found that if I added this method to the top of my Controller RSpec test case, then it resolved the issue entirely.

```
def main_app
  Rails.application.class.routes.url_helpers
end
```

I think this issue is related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13944991/undefined-local-variable-or-method-main-app-on-helper-test)