# How to run rails Devise method edit_password_url by hand?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

We have a user whose mail provider seems to be blocking the account from which we send the password reset emails.

I wanted to just get the reset-password-URL running from irb, and mail it by hand.  I can't seem to figure out how to run this thing "edit_password_url" or where it lives or in what scope it is defined.

Any tips on how to generate a reset-password url for a user by hand in irb?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it through the console with a little bit of work.  Here is how I approached it:

start rails console in your terminal:

`$rails c`

I looked at the [devise mailer](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/d75fd56f150f006aee51dcafc7157454190de570/app/views/devise/mailer/reset_password_instructions.html.erb#L5) view to see what it was calling to create the reset password URL:

```
<p><%= link_to 'Change my password', edit_password_url(@resource, :reset_password_token => @token) %></p>
```

The `@resource` in this code is your user, and the `@token` is their reset password token

Find your user by id, email or whatever.  Then find their reset password token:

```
u = User.find(1)
token = u.reset_password_token
```

To get access to the view you will need to create an instance of ActionView::Base

```
view = ActionView::Base.new
```

I then tried to access the url helper, but devise complains about

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `main_app' for #<ActionView::Base>
```

So I had to type a method into the console to fix that error (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16174184/main-app-namespace-unknown-in-rspec-only-in-unit-suite-tests-batch)):

```
def main_app
  Rails.application.class.routes.url_helpers
end
```

Depending on whether you have your mailer configured correctly in the rails console environment you are in, you may get some errors about the :host param not being set up.  To avoid this you could just call `_path` instead of `_url`.  Now you can call the url helper and pass the variables you set for user and token:

```
edit_password_path(u, :reset_password_token => token)

=> /users/password/edit?reset_password_token=123
```

The short answer is that you need to find their reset_password_token and append it to this URL:

```
http://yourdomain.com/users/password/edit?reset_password_token=<password-token-here>
```

Comment: Thank you!  I was also confused because when I sent it to myself I got this massive link like:   http://sendgrid.me/wf/click?upn=eb3n2OKd...(whole bunch of base64 gibberish).  But when I logged out and entered that URL above with the reset password token, I got the proper form.   Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

In Devise 3.3, I did the following:

```
$ bin/rails c
> include Devise::Controllers::UrlHelpers
```

Answer (score 1):

I recently found myself in a similar spam-folder situation.

This snippet worked nicely for me with rails 4, devise 4.3.

It also sends the reset password email, but for the sake of simplicity I think that's fine.

```
user = User.find(123)

token = user.send_reset_password_instructions

Rails
  .application
  .routes
  .url_helpers
  .edit_user_password_url(user, reset_password_token: token)
```

Comment: The reset_password_token stored in db is not used to generate the url directly. I need to use the return token. Thank you so much.