# How to controller test rails 4 engine redirect back to main_app routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rails-engines

I am having some trouble controller testing a rails engine that I created. The issue I am having is I can't seem to get rspec to use main_app routes.

For instance, I am writing the following controller test. The test would pass if it wasn't for the main_app.root_path returning nil.

The code I have in my controller spec is:

```
context "successful session creation" do
    let(:user) {FactoryGirl.create :user}

    it 'sets user id session' do
      get :create, use_route: :authenticatable, email: user.email, password: 'password'
      expect(session[:user_id]).to eq user.id
    end
  end
end
```

In my controller I have:

```
def create
  user = Authenticatable::User.find_by(email: params[:email])
  if user && user.login(params[:password])
    session[:user_id] = user.id
    redirect_to main_app.root_path, notice: "You are signed in!"
  else
    flash[:error] = 'Invalid email or password'
    redirect_to authenticatable.sign_in_path
  end
end
```

The rspec failure I get is:

```
NameError:
   undefined local variable or method `main_app' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::AuthenticatableSessionsController::GETCreate:0x007f9f583d6f18>
```

How can I make it so that rspec will use all of the route helpers available to me.

My rails_helper.rb file is as follows:

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require 'spec_helper'
require File.expand_path("../dummy/config/environment.rb", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'factory_girl_rails'
require 'shoulda-matchers'
require 'pry'
require 'database_cleaner'
Rails.backtrace_cleaner.remove_silencers!
# Load support files
Dir["#{File.dirname(__FILE__)}/support/**/*.rb"].each { |f| require f }
```

Thanks in advance for any help or suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there are otherswith similar problems ... I didn't have a chance to try this out myself but take a look at.

[stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13944991/undefined-local-variable-or-method-main-app-on-helper-test)

```
def main_app
  Rails.application.class.routes.url_helpers
end

main_app.root_path
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your a life savor. I have been searching for an answer for almost a week. The last thing I tried to use was Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.stub(main_app.root_path).and_return but didn't have any luck.

Comment: credit goes to @wintersolutions for his or her answer on the page linked to. I wish I could take credit for this.

Comment: where do you put this?

Answer (score 0):

just put it directly in you controller test file or in rails helper, just like a separate method