# Why are these tests not working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I ran into a problem and found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25232625/how-to-controller-test-rails-4-engine-redirect-back-to-main-app-routes) which I believe would solve my problem, but I can't get it to work.

Here's my code:

```
setup do
  # where the hell do I put this
  def main_app
    Rails.application.class.routes.url_helpers
  end
  @routes = Engine.routes
end

test "should get index" do
  get :index
  assert_response :success
end
```

---

```
blaine@vm:~/sizzle-chisel$ rake test
Started with run options --seed 60111

ERROR["test_should_get_index", Blog::Admin::ArticlesControllerTest, 0.3109516409999742]
 test_should_get_index#Blog::Admin::ArticlesControllerTest (0.31s)
ActionView::Template::Error:         ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method `root_path' for #<ActionDispatch::Routing::
RoutesProxy:0x00000006eda278>
```

---

```
Blog::Engine.routes.draw do
  root "articles#index"

  resources :articles

  namespace :admin do
    resources :articles
    root to: 'articles#index'
  end
end
```

I keep getting root_path is undefined, because within my layout, there's this code:

```
<%= link_to "some link", main_app.root_path %>
```

My codebase is Rails engine... so when I run rake test, there is no root_path defined on main_app.

Answer (score 0):

First, you can remove the setup block.

And try with:

```
test "should get index" do
  get '/'
  assert_response :success
end
```

`root "articles#index"` maps the `root`(http://mywebsite.com) of your website to the action `index` on the `articles` controller.

Comment: this does not answer my question... read the link I posted. I don't think you understand my problem.